# Graceful termination of a thread

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

Consider a multithreaded windows server application. for the sake of generality, let us assume all threads are running the same function:

```
DWORD WINAPI threaded_function(LPVOID p)
{
  while (TRUE) { // do things } 
}
```

Also , lets assume we're keeping references for all these threads.
What would be the best practice for a graceful termination?
(Keep in mind that as a service , we share a process among an unknown number of services and any kind of process termination methods are out of question)

My best guess would be:

1. Altering the `while (TRUE)` statement , with `while(global_event.not_signaled() )` (`where global_event` is an instance of a class that wrap the `Win32` `Event` object and the method called is obvious)
2. Now, implement the termination function as follow:

   global_event.set();
    Sleep(/* what would be a reasonable time to wait here? */ );
    thread_container.terminate_all();

The restriction we have, is that the application must eventually finish execution of all of it thread, and release all of it's VM and resources among of which are the thread's kernel objects.

Is there any better way to do this? are there any disadvantages in the specified method?

Comment: One common method is to test a per-thread flag and exit the function if it is set. Using a window loop and exiting on the `WM_QUIT` message is one way to do it.

Comment: As a side note: if `// do things` is lengthy, you might want to check the `global_event` at points throughout the code if it is possible to stop mid-execution. Otherwise, you have to wait for the full loop body to complete.

Comment: There is no reasonable time to wait. If the background thread fails to shut down, you have no choice but to terminate the process. Terminating threads will just corrupt data.

Comment: @AlexandreC. the discussed application is not windows oriented, so I don't wan't to insert the unnecessary notation. Does it have any advantages on my proposal?

Comment: @EdgarJamesluffternstat: pthreads have cancellation points -- they are exactly suited here. However, they don't exist under Windows, the window message pump trick deals with the synchronization for you (and your question is explicitly tagged with `winapi`).

Comment: Rereading my comment I can see now that it was unclear. It is definitely a windows application. what I meant was that it's not windows driven , in the sense that I have no GUI, nor a single window- objects.

Comment: @AlexandreC. Last comment should have been tagged for you.

Comment: You don't need a GUI to have a Win32 message pump. It is a useful trick for COM marshalling too.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a mutex and take it on the caller thread, like:

```
void caller(){
HANDLE mutex;
CreateMutex(mutex);

WaitForSingleObject(mutex); // take the mutex ownership

createThread(threadedfunction, mutex);

// do things

ReleaseMutex(mutex);

//end
}
```

And on your threadedfunction wait for the release like:

```
void threadefunction(HANDLE mutex){

  while(WaitForSingleObject(mutex,1)==WAIT_TIMEOUT){
    // do things
  }
  ReleaseMutex(mutex);
}
```

This way you threadedfunction will keep runing while the mutex can't be taken, the waitforsingleobject will be timing-out with one milisecond wait and do things until it can take the mutex and exit.

Comment: A waitable event that is signaled at termination time is more common, and just makes more sense, than timing out on an owned mutex.

Comment: But how do manage to keep running the process while the event is not signaled? If i'm waiting for signaling with a WaitForSingleObject(INFINITE) there is no running something else while waiting...

Comment: Obviously, you would not use `INFINITE`, you would use a timeout instead, and only terminate the thread if the wait on the event reports `WAIT_OBJECT_0`.